# Mozilla Add-on SDK documentation download

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk, offline, mozilla

Is there a way to download the [documentation for the Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK)?

In previous versions, you could type

```
cfx docs
```

to browse a local copy, yet [cfx is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx) and the docs option was removed even before that.

https://github.com/neiesc/dochub seems like a way to go, but fails on nodejs 0.12.

---

Not working:

- The last commit with the `cfx docs` command is [97d77223](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/commit/97d77223b48475984446c8cb31d1e84a80ce0b2c). The documentation is in markdown files in the repository, and thus, obsolete.
- The [Add-on SDK](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/) does not contain enough comments to generate the documentation from it. There is f.ex. no info about `page-mod` in its files in `lib/sdk`.
- http://devdocs.io/ has a proposal to import, but it is in the middle of the proposals vote-wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the naive wget approach is the stylesheet, which has a URL with a `?` and is probably not recognized by wget. To fix, after

1. downloading all docs via

   ```
   wget --continue --adjust-extension --recursive --page-requisites --convert-links --level=inf --no-parent --wait=1 'https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK'
   ```
2. download the stylesheet manually

   ```
   wget https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/css/mdn-min.css?build=0e7ce0f
   ```
3. rename

   ```
   mv mdn-min.css?build=0e7ce0f mdn-min.css
   ```
4. copy to every sub-directory

   ```
   find . -type d -exec cp mdn-min.css {} \;
   ```
5. and alter all files to use the local stylesheet:

   ```
   find . -type f -exec sed -i 's!https\:\/\/developer\.cdn\.mozilla\.net\/media\/css\/mdn-min.css!mdn-min.css!g' {} \;
   ```

Comment: This is a kludge. If you know better solutions, they are welcome.